# How to generate Protobuf Duration for Enrollment Token?

Tags: .net, protocol-buffers, android-management-api

I am trying to create an enrollment token that expires at the end of the day. However, when I try to send a Create Request, I get the following message:

```
service androidmanagement has thrown an exception.
HttpStatusCode is BadRequest.
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "Seconds" at 'enrollment_token.duration': Cannot find field.
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "Nanos" at 'enrollment_token.duration': Cannot find field. [400]
Errors [
        Message[Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "Seconds" at 'enrollment_token.duration': Cannot find field.
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "Nanos" at 'enrollment_token.duration': Cannot find field.] Location[ - ] Reason[invalid] Domain[]
]
```

When I debug the token I receive from my original request, the `Duration` field is `(null)`. There is an `ExperationTimestamp` of 1 hr since creation.

The website says we can customize the duration: https://developers.google.com/android/management/provision-device#create_an_enrollment_token

But looking at the documentation for creating new Enrollment Tokens, there is no field to customize duration: https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.enrollmentTokens/create

Is this a deprecated feature?

The complete code I am using is here:

```
    // Calculate Duration
    Timestamp now = Timestamp.FromDateTime(DateTime.UtcNow);
    Timestamp tomorrow = Timestamp.FromDateTime(DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).ToUniversalTime());

    // Create a token with a policy name. Whatever device provisioned with this token will use this policy
    EnrollmentToken token = new EnrollmentToken();
    token.PolicyName = policyID;
    token.Duration = tomorrow - now;

    // Build and execute a request to tie the token to our enterprise
    EnterprisesResource.EnrollmentTokensResource.CreateRequest request = androidManagementService.Enterprises.EnrollmentTokens.Create(token, enterprise.Name);
    var result = request.Execute();
```

Comment: What is type of `token.Duration`? String? What is the value of `tomorrow-now` in your code? The documentation for [`EnrollmentToken`](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.enrollmentTokens#EnrollmentToken) is confusing but, I think (!?) if `token.Duration` is a string, you may be able to use `86400s` as the value. See [`duration.proto`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/d41deb9dc6602701b157739a314ad6405f9b89ed/src/google/protobuf/duration.proto#L94)

Comment: The .NET SDK error messages are... unhelpful too... though they suggest that you're sending a `Duration` type which has fields `Seconds` and `Nanoseconds`. And this is not what's expected for the message's [`Duration`](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.enrollmentTokens#EnrollmentToken.FIELDS.duration) which is a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package says `token.Duration` is an `object`. I assumed it wanted a `Duration` class.

However, the api only accepts a `string` of format `{timeInSeconds}s`

This is the working piece of code:

```
    // Calculate Duration
    var expirationTimeSpan = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1) - DateTime.Now;
    string expireDurationString = expirationTimeSpan.TotalSeconds.ToString() + "s";

    // Create a token with a policy name. Whatever device provisioned with this token will use this policy
    EnrollmentToken token = new EnrollmentToken();
    token.PolicyName = policyID;
    token.Duration = expireDurationString;

    // Build and execute a request to tie the token to our enterprise
    EnterprisesResource.EnrollmentTokensResource.CreateRequest request = androidManagementService.Enterprises.EnrollmentTokens.Create(token, enterprise.Name);
    var result = request.Execute();
```

Comment: Maxi’s comment is correct. The Duration field is being set to the incorrect data type. You are using the java type TimeStamp, but per the enrollmentToken [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.enrollmentTokens#EnrollmentToken.FIELDS.duration), the value passed in the Duration field is a string representation of the Duration format. Essentially, you are not converting timestamp to duration. [(example code snippet)](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/#duration)

Comment: As per the example in the Duration doc, before assigning the value to the token. Duration, you should convert the “tomorrow” and “now” Timestamps in seconds and cast it to a Duration type.